# Highlight table row depending on variable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom drupal module and I'm creating a table using theme 'table'.

```
$header = array();
$header[] = array("data" => "Home Team");
$header[] = array("data" => "Away Team");

$row = array();

foreach ($node as $game) {
  $row = [$hometeam), $awayteam)];
  $rows[] = $row;
}

$table = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));

return $table;
```

I'm also using Bootstrap theme in my site.
I want to highlight all the rows where some variable meets a requirement. For example, highlight all the rows where 'Home Team' == 'something'.

It seems to me that I can't override the theme classes or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build your rows like you did your header there, you can set attributes for the rows or cells. There's an example in the [theme_table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) documentation of adding a class to a row.

```
$rows = array(
  // Simple row
  array(
    'Cell 1', 'Cell 2', 'Cell 3'
  ),
  // Row with attributes on the row and some of its cells.
  array(
    'data' => array(
      'Cell 1', 
      array('data' => 'Cell 2', 'colspan' => 2)
    ), 
    'class' => array('funky') // <-- row class
  )
);
```